# What is the right syntax on how to count the votes

Tags: c#, mysql

This is the code that we used to COUNT the number of students who voted.

```
SELECT candidate,position, COUNT(studentNumber) AS 'Candidate Votes'
FROM dbvotingsystem.votes WHERE organization = 'iSITE' GROUP BY candidate
ORDER BY position;
```

The image is the sample of the data in the table.

[image]om/CwvSt.png

Comment: Please format your code and explain what the problem is

Comment: The question doesn´t seem to have anything to do with C#, it´s just SQL.

Comment: Sorry, yeah you're right it's just mysql.

Comment: Provide complete dataset and table definition, Probably good if you can use http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Your table doesn't appear to have position in it, where does that come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `winner` is the max `Candidate Votes` in each group, then `Secretary`'s winner should be `Many`, check the following sql:

```
SELECT
    position,
    substring_index(group_concat(candidate order by `Candidate Votes` desc), ',', 1) winner,
    max(`Candidate Votes`) as `Candidate Votes`
FROM (
    SELECT candidate, position, COUNT(studentNumber) AS 'Candidate Votes'
    FROM dbvotingsystem.votes
    WHERE organization = 'iSITE'
    GROUP BY candidate
) votes
GROUP BY position
```

Result:

```
|    position | winner | Candidate Votes |
|-------------|--------|-----------------|
|   President | Audrey |               7 |
|   Secretary |   Many |               8 |
|   Treasurer |  Barry |              10 |
| V.President |   Juan |               9 |
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecd1aa/4) in SQLFiddle.

Comment: What if 2 persons of same position get equal votes ?

Comment: For example, among the candidates who are running for president audrey got the highest votes. But it should display audreys vote only not all the votes of the candidates who are running for president.        
  position         | Winner      | Candidate Votes
 President        | Audrey      | 7
 Secretary        | Clark       | 8
 Treasurer        | Barry       | 10
 V.President      | Juan        | 9

Comment: @Michelle Updated the answer.

Comment: It should only display the number of votes the winner has. But in your statement, it adds all the votes from other candidates too with the same position.

Comment: @Michelle Like **@M Khalid Junaid** said, if 2 persons of same position get equal votes, the result is like what?

Comment: Sir, I'm sorry but can I ask what is substring_index and group_concat?

Comment: @Michelle Check the official document: [substring_index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: @Forward we haven't thought of that. Hmm, can you give us some advice?

Comment: The votes per candidate are not inputted directly it is COUNTed within the sql statement as shown here,                                                  SELECT candidate,position, COUNT(studentNumber) AS 'Candidate Votes'
FROM dbvotingsystem.votes WHERE organization = 'iSITE' GROUP BY candidate
ORDER BY position;

Comment: @Michelle Please post entirely db data in your op. Then I can help better.

Comment: @Michelle See my edited answer, one point should be paid attention, cause you `group by candidate` in sub-query, so the `position` in sub-query is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it using a variables to rank the results. Note the way the group by uses all the selected columns and that draws are catered for.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int auto_increment primary key, candidate varchar(1),position varchar(3));

insert into t (candidate,position) values
('a','p'),('b','p'),('a','p'),
('c','vp'),('c','vp'),('d','vp'),('d','vp');

select position,candidate, votes, rn as rank
from
(
select position,candidate, votes,
         if(s.position <> @p,@rn:=1,if(s.votes <> @v,@rn+1,@rn=1)) rn,
         @p:=position p,
         @v:=votes v
from
(
select position,candidate , count(*) as votes 
from t
group by position,candidate 
) s
,(select @rn:=0,@p:='',@v:='') r
order by position,candidate, votes desc
) t
where rn = 1
```